# Dnn Menu Control in IE

Tags: css, dotnetnuke

I had a dnn slide menu where I am having the problem only in IE, 
Only One of the sub item is not being displayed only in IE, when I inspect the element the structure is  as below in IE.,

```
<span style="vertical-align: middle; display: table-cell;" ?="" vertical-align:middle;="" display:table-cell;=""/>
```

In Firefox browser it is like this

```
<span style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; width:18px;"></span>
<span style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; ">E-Participation</span>
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: may i ask what is `?=""` ?

Comment: That is what I don't know why the structure is becoming like this, 

This is the structure I am getting when I inspect the element @NullPointer

Comment: Then show us the source html (including some context)

Comment: the original source html (for instance "view source" in your browser and copy and paste here)

Comment: Since it is a CMS System if I see the source it will not be in our common structure @ori

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last found the solution by changing the respective page setting, by unchecking the checkbox disabled it is working fine.
But still I didn't get why it is working fine in firefox and not working fine in IE7